# Segregate object with similar properties in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
[
   {"Subject": "Physics", "Active": 48, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 45, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 40, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "English", "Active": 41, "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 46, "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 42, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 40, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Physics", "Active": 44, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Hindi", "Active": 38, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "English", "Active": 41, "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Hindi", "Active": 42, "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 33, "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 35, "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z"}
]
```

I need to segregate this data by adding actives based on Date. Then I need it to be pushed in another array of objects. Something like this:

```
[{
    "Active": 133,
    "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"
},
{
    "Active": 87,
    "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z"
},
{
    "Active": 164,
    "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"
},
{
    "Active": 83,
    "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z"
},
{
    "Active": 68,
    "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I propose

```js
datas = [
   {"Subject": "Physics", "Active": 48, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 45, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 40, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "English", "Active": 41, "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 46, "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 42, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 40, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Physics", "Active": 44, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Hindi", "Active": 38, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "English", "Active": 41, "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Hindi", "Active": 42, "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 33, "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z"},
   {"Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 35, "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z"}
];

function segregate(datas) {
    return datas.reduce((c, data) => {
        if (!c[data.Date]) {
            c[data.Date] = {
                Active: data.Active,
                Date: data.Date,
            };
        } else {
            c[data.Date].Active += data.Active;
        }
        return c;
    }, {});

}

console.log(segregate(datas));
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to iterate over your array and return an object which has the Date values as keys, and the calculated sum of Active as values. Then you only have to convert it to an array of objects.

```js
const jsonObj = [
    { "Subject": "Physics", "Active": 48, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 45, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 40, "Date": "2020-01-22T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "English", "Active": 41, "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 46, "Date": "2020-01-23T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 42, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 40, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Physics", "Active": 44, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Hindi", "Active": 38, "Date": "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "English", "Active": 41, "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Hindi", "Active": 42, "Date": "2020-01-25T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Chemistry", "Active": 33, "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z" },
    { "Subject": "Mathematics", "Active": 35, "Date": "2020-01-26T00:00:00Z" }
]

const obj = jsonObj.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr.Date] = (prev[curr.Date] || 0) + curr.Active
    return prev
}, {})

const result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({ Date: key, Active: obj[key] })).sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : 0)

console.log(result)
```